# Crittercism does not catch some of the crashes

Tags: android, crittercism

I am on Android and using Crittercism to log the crashes but unfortunately it doesn't catch all the crashes. A lot of the missed crashes are `OutOfMemoryException`s, but not all OOM exceptions are missed. I could not figure out any pattern as to when it gets caught and when it doesn't!! Anyone happens to know as to why this takes place or a way around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for missing Out of Memory exceptions is due to the nature of the JVM handling certain scenarios versus others.

I don't have a list of scenarios that the JVM kindly brushes under the rug (ie, not violently kill the app process), but in those cases Crittercism can function normally and capture the Java Out of Memory exception. In the other case where the JVM violently crashes, Crittercism will have difficulty capturing (however no crash reporter handles this as far as I know at this time).

As for other scenarios beyond OOM, here are two others scenario in which Crash Reporters (not just Crittercism) have difficulty capturing:

App Not Responding is another scenario that the OS kills the process and nothing can run or complete. As such, crash reporters can't capture this moment.

[Stack Overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow) is a case where the app gets into a corrupted state and the OS kills the process. Though I'm not 100% on this scenario.

That being said, on Android Crittercism is one of the few that provides a remote NDK exception tracking which will capture when the JVM crashes (ie Dalvik native exceptions/signals). But as I mentioned above it doesn't have the niceties of JVM managed memory so crashes are more volatile and OOM will get missed.

Hopefully that helps!